# Как установить virtualgl на ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get

Ввожу в терминале вот это:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends virtualgl
```

Мне выдает вот это:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package virtualgl is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'virtualgl' has no installation candidate
```

Как я понял нету нужного репозитория. Не подскажете как добавить нужны репозиторий? Заранее спасибо)

Хочу установить Bumblebee. 
Вот [тут](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/bumblebee) иду по инструкции для Ubuntu 16.04. Там нужно выполнить вот это

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends nvidia-361 nvidia-settings bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia primus virtualgl
```

И только `virtualgl` не хочет(

Comment: Версия Убунты какая?

Comment: @AndrewHobbit Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Xenial Xerus) AMD64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**обновление**: для версии дистрибутива 16.04 (xenial) сборки именно этого пакета от проекта bumblebee — [нет](http://ppa.launchpad.net/bumblebee/stable/ubuntu/dists/). вероятно, он либо устарел, либо заменён иным пакетом.

для более старых версий дистрибутива нижеприведённое вполне актуально (пока).

---

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable
$ sudo apt-get update
```

---

опцию `--install-recommends` указывать не обязательно — по умолчанию и так предлагается устанавить рекомендованные пакеты.

Comment: Все равно. `E: Package 'virtualgl' has no installation candidate`

Comment: @SkiesX, возможно, для вашей версии дистрибутива и архитектуры такой пакет не собран. посмотрите сами: http://ppa.launchpad.net/bumblebee/stable/ubuntu/dists/

Comment: у меня Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Xenial Xerus) AMD64

Comment: как видите, для *xenial* нет сборки. кстати, вероятно, не зря. вы уверены, что вам нужен именно этот пакет?

Comment: я дописал свой вопрос. посмотрите пожалуйста.

Comment: но возможно я понял в чем весь прикол. вот есть установка для xenial http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/bumblebee-xenial . там нет virtualgl